# What does "briefly noted" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, usage, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I often see the expression "briefly noted" on weblog posts (and also New Yorker). In general, what does it mean to say "something is briefly noted".

Some Examples:

[In New Yorker](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/briefly-noted)

[Its use in an academic journal](https://digitalcommons.pepperdine.edu/naalj/vol3/iss2/8/)

[The Brad DeLong's weblog](https://www.bradford-delong.com/2021/03/sidney-coleman-is-my-interpretation-of-quantum-mechanics-guru-plus-briefly-noted-for-2021-12-17-we.html)

Comment: Yes...the Q should be self-contained. The comments are intended to clarify the question...but NOT just the link, also the citation.

Comment: All those examples are titles, which don't obey the rules of grammar or meaning, and some of them look like they are deliberately intended to be plays on words.

Comment: What exactly about that phrase needs to be explained?

Comment: IMO, it is just another way to say [_in brief_](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-brief)

Answer (score 1):

To "note" something is to recognize and then acknowledge or comment on it. To do something "briefly" is to do it for a short period of time. (Or, in reference to saying or writing something, to do so concisely or using only a few words.)

If something is "briefly noted", that means that one is only saying a little bit about it rather than describing it in depth.

Comment: +1 "[Briefly](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/briefly)" also means "using only a few words" or concisely, which might fit better when we're talking about blogs and journals.

Comment: Good point. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

"Briefly Noted" is usually a category of "shorter than usual" articles in a magazine or other long-form publication. If the typical article is 1200 words, a "briefly noted" article might be 600 words or less.

For example, in the [Pennsylvania Gazette Briefly Noted section](https://thepenngazette.com/briefly-noted-44/), there are only two or three sentences about each topic. [A typical feature story](https://thepenngazette.com/power-of-the-pup/) from the same publication is much longer—fifty or more paragraphs.